# How to bind variable declared with Svelte let directive?

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to workaround "Cannot bind to a variable declared with the let: directive" error.

```
// FancyList.svelte
<script>
    export let items = []   
</script>

<ul>
    {#each items as item, i}
        <li><slot item={item}></slot></li>
    {/each} 
</ul>

// App.svelte
<script>
    import FancyList from './FancyList.svelte'
    let items = [ {x: 'AX', y: 'AY'}, {x: 'BX', y: 'BY'}, {x: 'CX', y: 'CY'}]
</script>

<FancyList bind:items={items} let:item={item}>
    <input type=text bind:value={item.x}>
    <input type=text bind:value={item.y}>
</FancyList>
```

Available as [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/bc985c21735f4b2a9945f1ddc74988e6?version=3.6.1)

## Things I have tried so far

1) Making `FancyList` to pass item index instead of item itself and binding `items[index]` instead of `item`.

```
<FancyList items={items} let:index={index}>
    <input type=text bind:value={items[index].x}>
    <input type=text bind:value={items[index].y}>
</FancyList>
```

Available as [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0c17578d7d2e45d7b142d89ef1a8db90?version=3.6.1)

This will initially render properly but will emit "ReferenceError: index is not defined" error upon input value change.

2) Making `FancyList` to pass `onChange` callback and not using `bind`.

```
<FancyList bind:items={items} let:item={item} let:onChange={onChange}>
    <input type=text value={item.x} on:input={e => onChange({...item, x: e.target.value})}>
    <input type=text value={item.y} on:input={e => onChange({...item, y: e.target.value})}>
</FancyList>
```

Available as [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/54510cf0c9044c459d1981fd6265d04b?version=3.6.1).

This works but is significantly more verbose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bug that your first solution attempt didn't work — I've [raised an issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3140). Another possible workaround is to put the update logic in the parent component, so that the child component doesn't need to have any special awareness of the parent's requirements: https://svelte.dev/repl/2d13c33c34f445d99618fbb1bc8bebb9?version=3.6.1. It's about the same as your second solution, verbosity-wise.

Comment: This throws an error that it can't bind to a variable declared with the `let:` directive

Answer (score 2):

You can use `svelte:component` to accomplish this. It basically will let you pass a component to your FancyList, making it a Higher Order Component of sorts.

Here's a REPL example that shows it working:

https://svelte.dev/repl/bc985c21735f4b2a9945f1ddc74988e6?version=3.6.1

Comment: That REPL has the same error `Cannot bind to a variable declared with the let: directive`

Comment: something must have changed ‍♂️