# Svelte/yrv router: how can I access router parameters in a component?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Similar to [How to bind variable declared with Svelte let directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817063/how-to-bind-variable-declared-with-svelte-let-directive), but that issue was caused by a Svelte bug that is now, apparently fixed - this is occuring on Svelte 3.23.0, the latest available.

I am using Svelte and the [yrv router](https://github.com/pateketrueke/yrv). I want to be able to access the `router` variable inside a component, specifically the `slug` param.

```js
<Router>

  <Route exact path="/:slug" let:router>
    <WorkDetail {works} bind:slug={router.params.slug} />
    Hey {router.params.slug}!
  </Route>

</Router>
```

When I build this, Svelte complains:

> ValidationError: Cannot bind to a variable declared with the let: directive

**How can I access `router` parameters in a component?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to `bind:` here, it's ok to just do

```
<WorkDetail {works} slug={router.params.slug} />
```

If you want to use `router` on the outer component, then you could immediately call a method to set it like so:

```
<script>

// ...

let router;
function setRouter(r) {
  router = r;
  return '';  // the return value of this method call will be rendered, prints undefined if we don't return someting
}

</script>

<Router>

  <Route exact path="/:slug" let:router>
    {setRouter(router)}
    <WorkDetail {works} slug={router.params.slug} />
    Hey {router.params.slug}!
  </Route>

</Router>
```

Here's a simpified REPL:
https://svelte.dev/repl/a5ab1904ecdd47b39c3575125f95d9d6?version=3.23.0

Answer (score 1):

you can use PROPS to child component

**example**

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
import {Router,Route,Link} from 'yrv'
import Food from './Food.svelte'
</script>


<Router>
 <Route path="/about/:name">
<About name={router.params.name}/>
</Route>
</Router>
```

**in Child Component**

```
<script>
export let name;
</srcipt>
<p>HERE params : {name}</p>
```